# Get most recent record for each type

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have an entity table called metrics, and each metric has a value which changes over time.  I store this changing value in another table called metric_history.

### metrics:

```
id, name, category
1, File, Disk
2, CPU, Hardware
3, Memory, Hardware
4, MySQL, Database
```

### metric_history:

```
id, mId, value, recordCreated
1, 1, lorem, 2019-02-06 15:19:33
2, 1, ipsum, 2019-02-06 15:19:43
3, 2, at, 2019-02-06 15:37:48
4, 1, dolor, 2019-02-06 15:41:31
5, 2, vero, 2019-02-06 15:42:02
6, 1, sit, 2019-02-06 15:47:15
7, 2, eos, 2019-02-06 15:49:11
8, 1, amet, 2019-02-06 15:50:59
9, 4, sed, 2019-02-06 15:54:09
```

I'm trying to build a query that would return me the most recent timestamp for each, so in the example would be:

### Results:

```
8, 1, amet, 2019-02-06 15:50:59
7, 2, eos, 2019-02-06 15:49:11
9, 4, sed, 2019-02-06 15:54:09
```

I'm seemingly going around in circles trying to find an elegant query but now doubting my table design.  Here's where I'm at, seems to work:

```
SELECT id, dmId, value, recordCreated
FROM metric_history
WHERE (dmId, recordCreated)
IN (SELECT DISTINCT dmId, MAX(recordCreated) FROM metric_history GROUP BY dmId)
```

The other alternative that I can see is to have an additional timestamp column in the metrics table and update that every time I update the history table but that doesn't seem right either.

Should I be writing a query here or is my table design wrong?  I'm leaning towards the former.

Comment: This type of question is asked frequently. I added the tag [tag:greatest-n-per-group] so you could see some other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Using MySQL-8.0, MariaDB-10.2 you can use window functions to get an answer [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a3570784a25f9fad36a5e3e552c7b2b):

```
SELECT id, mId, value, recordCreated
FROM ( 
  SELECT 
    id, mId, value, recordCreated,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mId ORDER BY recordCreated DESC) AS `rank`
  FROM metric_history 
  ORDER BY id 
) AS tmp 
WHERE tmp.`rank` = 1
```